# Array reduce assinging variable ouside the function

Tags: php

I want to flatten multidimensional array to single dimensional so I use `array_reduce()` to get it done.
But struck in this place.

```
$array = array
            (
                1 => array
                    (
                        0 => 1,
                        1 => 'a'                 
                    ),

                2 => array
                    (
                        0 => 2,
                        1 => 'b'                 
                    )
            )
```

**Code :**

```
$key = 1;   
$array_reduced = array_reduce( $array,function(&$result, $item){    
                        $result[] = $item[$key];
                        return $result;                                 
                        }); 
print_r($array_reduced);
```

**Output Should be :**

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => a

     [1] => b
 )
```

Which shows `Undefined variable: key` in this line `$result[] = $item[$key];`
If I replace the `$item[$key]` to `$item[1]` its working.

How to use `$key` in `array_reduce()`.

Comment: What is the pattern behind this that you only grab a and b ?

Comment: @Rizier123 its just an example i have array of 20 index so it should be flatten it can be done by `for loop` easily but have curiosity why `$key` is not able to assign.

Comment: It is out of scope in the closure!

Comment: @Rizier123 you got the point. Is there any way to get it done.

Comment: Well here I would use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (example #3)

Comment: @Rizier123 how it will work in my case.

Comment: It would look like this: `array_reduce( $array,function(&$result, $item)use($key){ $result[] = $item[$key]; $key++;
                        return $result;}); ` <- Also increment it

Comment: @Rizier123 worked !!!

Comment: Glad I could help you. (Should I put an answer in?)

Comment: @Rizier123 ya it will help some one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your problem is simply that the variable `$key` is out of scope in the closure function. So you could either use the keyword `global` (which isn't the nicest) or [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). So I would recommend you to use `use()` like this:

```
array_reduce($array, function(&$result, $item)use($key){  //<-- See use
    $result[] = $item[$key];
    $key++;  //Don't forget to increment your variable
    return $result;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$key = 1;   
$array_reduced = array_reduce( $array,function(&$result, $item){  
                        $key++;
                        $result[] = $item[$key];
                        return $result;                                 
                        }); 
print_r($array_reduced);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b )
```